# Matching Aspect Ratios between two GeoGraphics with Entities for GeoRange

Tags: options, geography, geographics, entity

I'm making a basic 50-state map of population (using a log scale). Given the usual crucible of figuring out what to do with Hawaii and Alaska, I thought I would make the same `GeoRegionValuePlot` three times with the same dataset, and use `GeoRange` to center one each on the continental US, on AK, and on HI (thus keeping the color scales consistent), and arrange them with a `GraphicsGrid`.

This worked fine, except that the GeoRange of Alaska, at an `ImageSize` of 240, is `{240, 150}`, while Hawaii is `{240, 157}`:

```
contentinal = GeoRegionValuePlot[populationLog, GeoRange->Entity["Country","UnitedStates"], ImageSize->500, PlotLegends->None];
ak = GeoRegionValuePlot[populationLog, GeoRange->Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Alaska","UnitedStates"}], ImageSize->240, PlotLegends->None];
hi = GeoRegionValuePlot[populationLog, GeoRange->Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Hawaii","UnitedStates"}], ImageSize->240, PlotLegends->None];

Grid[{
    { contentinal, SpanFromLeft },
    { hi, ak }
}, Frame->All]
```

[image]

To be sure, worse fates have befallen humanity, but this really irritates me. Of course, I could force AK and HI to the same size, but that would distort one or the other.

What I want is a way to center a map on an Entity, as I'm doing, but then dictate the aspect ratio so that, in this case, the viewport for Alaska goes a few ticks farther north and south so that it matches Hawaii's aspect ratio. Does that make sense? I think I know how to do it the hard way, but I'm hoping there's an elegant solution that combines `GeoRange` and `AspectRatio` without skewing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this satisfies your desire for elegance but you can get there by specifying the right value for [`GeoRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRangePadding.html).

For example on my system I get plot heights of 152 and 157, so a [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) value of 0.03 normalizes them.

To create a more extreme example I shall use California.

```
pop = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {#, "UnitedStates"}] -> #2 & @@@ {{"Alaska", 
     740}, {"California", 39540}};

{ak, ca} = GeoRegionValuePlot[pop, 
     GeoRange -> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {#, "UnitedStates"}], 
     GeoRangePadding -> {Scaled[#2], None}, ImageSize -> 240, 
     PlotLegends -> None] & @@@ {{"Alaska", 0.91}, {"California", 0}};

Grid[{{ca, ak}, {ak, ca}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me! Thanks much

Comment: @Chris Glad I could help! :-)